# Error returning value addOnSuccesListener Kotlin

Tags: android, function, kotlin

I am devoling a restaurant review app. I am trying to check if an user has already posted a review of a restaurant. I have the function `fetchIfDataExist` which access to the Firebase Database and check if an user already has a review of a restaurant, if so, the value of `existingReview` is changed to `true`. The problem is that the function works properly and changes the value of `existingReview` to `true` but I don't know why the `if else` statement after `Log.d("URL_DEBUG", "fuera: $existingReview")` and this line, are executing first. So despite the value of `existingReview` is changed to `true`, the value is always `false`. I suppose is something related with how `addOnSuccesListener`  works and returns values. Could anyone help me please?

```
  if (email == "guest_email") {
            //Can not post a review
            showAlertAuth()
        } else {
            fetchIfDataExist(placeName)

            Log.d("URL_DEBUG", "fuera: $existingReview")

            if (existingReview) { //The user has already posted a review
                showAlertExistingReview()
            } else {
                val intent = Intent(this, ReviewActivity::class.java).apply {
                    putExtra("email", email)
                    putExtra("restaurant", placeName)
                    putExtra("edit", false)
                }
                startActivity(intent)
            }
```

```
   var existingReview = false
    private fun fetchIfDataExist(restaurant: String) {
        Log.d("URL_DEBUG", "restaurant name: $restaurant")
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("user_review")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                for (document in result) {
                    if (document.id.contains(email)) {
                        val user = document.toObject(User_Review::class.java)
                        Log.d("URL_DEBUG", "restaurant: ${user.restaurant}")
                        Log.d("URL_DEBUG", "check: ${user.restaurant == restaurant}")
                        if (user.restaurant == restaurant) {
                            existingReview = true
                            Log.d("URL_DEBUG", "Inside: $existingReview")
                            return@addOnSuccessListener
                        } else {
                            existingReview = false
                        }
                    }
                    Log.d("URL_DEBUG", "existingReview: $existingReview")
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error UserBookmarkRecyclerViewActivity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()
            }
    }
```

Comment: `fetchIfDataExist` returns immediately after setting up the listeners and that's why `Log.d("URL_DEBUG", "fuera: $existingReview")` is run before the code inside success listener. The code inside the listener is executed only when the request completes.

Comment: So what do I need to do to know if a user is on my database. Becouse I would like to do by changing the value of ```existingReview```, but I don't know how to do it